# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un subprograma me muestre los datos de otro subprograma?

Tags: c++

```
void mostrar_pedido (const Pedido & ped){
    cout<<ped.nombre <<" " <<ped.num_ingredientes <<" " <<ped.lista_ingredientes;
}

void mostrar_pedidos (const Pizzeria & pz){
    cout<<pz.num_pedidos <<endl;
}
```

En mostrar pedidos necesito añadir también los datos de mostrar pedido, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Interfaces de pedido y pizzería

```
struct Pedido{
    string nombre;
    int num_ingredientes;
    Lista_Ingredientes lista_ingredientes;
};

struct Pizzeria{
    int num_pedidos;
    Lista_Pedidos lista_pedidos;
};
```

Comment: Sería interesante que mostrases la interfaz de `Pedido` y de `Pizzeria`

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate que la clase `Pizzeria` tiene un listado de `Pedido`. Lo único que tienes que hacer es iterar sobre esa colección de elementos:

```
void mostrar_pedidos (const Pizzeria & pz){
    cout<<pz.num_pedidos <<endl;
    for( auto const& pedido : pz.lista_pedidos )
      mostrar_pedido(pedido);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de controlar los datos tal y como lo has descrito es teniendo claro como están estructurados.

Veo que lo has estructurado de manera que una pizzeria tiene una lista de pedidos.

Simplemente debes iterar por `Pizzeria.Lista_Pedidos()` tantas veces como pedidos haya `Pizzeria.num_pedidos`.

Como bien ha dicho eferion:

```
void mostrar_pedidos (const Pizzeria & pz)
{
    cout << pz.num_pedidos << endl;
    for(auto const& pedido:pz.lista_pedidos)
        mostrar_pedido(pedido);
}
```

Comment: que tiene de diferente tu respuesta a la de eferion?, por que yo veo el método void idéntico al que el propone